# multiple execute command for find and provide output in same line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, find

I am trying to make a single line bash script to gather the file name/location, size of file and type of file. I managed to do the same using the following script :

```
find . -type f -exec du {} \; -exec file -b {} \;
```

However the output of this comes in two lines :

```
0   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/test/test_tkinter/__init__.py
empty
```

I want to display them is a single line  in the following format :

```
0   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/test/test_tkinter/__init__.py
empty

size : file name : file type
```

Can any one guide me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a combination of Ed's approach but with the output from `file -b` appended.  It appears to work for me:

```
find . -type f -printf "%b : %p : " -exec file -b {} \;
```

The `%b` formatter is in 512 blocks which is what I see running `du` on files on my system.  You might like `%k` for 1024K blocks instead or the `%s` that Ed has shown.  The `%p` formatter outputs the full file name.  The output isn't given a carriage return in the `printf` formatter and then the exec happens.  I couldn't find a formatter for providing the `file -b` functionality.

For example:

```
find . -type f -printf "%b : %p : " -exec file -b {} \;
8 : ./data : ASCII text
8 : ./awko : data
0 : ./nothing : empty
8 : ./data2 : ASCII text
```

Here's a link to the [find man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) that I used.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the `-printf` arg in the `find` man page?

```
$ ls -al
total 65
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Ed None 0 Feb 10 19:38 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Ed None 0 Feb  9 08:41 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 Ed None 2 Feb 10 19:40 a
-rw-r--r--  1 Ed None 0 Feb 10 19:38 b

$ find . -printf "%s : %p : %y\n"
0 : . : d
2 : ./a : f
0 : ./b : f
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you. See the notes below with assumptions and explanations.

```
$ find so -type f -exec du {} \; -exec file -b {} \; | awk -F\t 'NF > 1 { printf "%s:%s:", $1, $2 ; next }1'
8:so/a.txt:ASCII text
8:so/anotherfile.txt:ASCII text
8:so/b1.txt:ASCII text
8:so/b2.txt:ASCII text
8:so/input.txt:ASCII text
8:so/long.txt:ASCII text, with very long lines
8:so/ref.txt:ASCII text
63504:so/somezip.zip:Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
8:so/this.is.a.file.txt:ASCII text
8:so/yet-still-another-file.txt:ASCII text
```

**Notes**

```
awk -F\t
```

Pipe the result of the find into awk, using tab as the separator. Here I'm assuming the `du` command separates the size from the file with a tab as it does in my environment.

```
NF > 1
```

If there is more than one field, we know it's the `du` output (here I'm assuming none of the types returned from `file` contain a tab character).

```
{ printf "%s:%s:", $1, $2 ; next }
```

Print the `du` output with colon separators, and *no* trailing newline. `next` tells it to skip immediately to the next line of input (the `file` output).

```
1
```

Idiomatic way of simply printing the input, (which is the `file` output), to stdout with a newline. (`1` is the pattern, always true, and the default action is to print the line.)

Answer (score 0):

```
find  -type f -exec sh -c 'du {};echo -n size:$(du --summarize --human-readable "{}"|cut -f1)"  ";echo -n filname:$(basename "{}");echo "  "filetype:$(file -b "{}")' \;
```